# Parallel.For running 100 times then stopping?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to run through a list, but my iteration will only run 100 times before stopping. I actually run it in parallel 6 times so it should definitly run more than 100 times, especially how I set the loop to 100k.

The code inside `for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)` seems to only run 100 times across all parallel threads. The queue has over 1 million items, so the queue isn't the problem here.

```
public class ProxyWorker
{
    private static int _proxyCount;
    private static ConcurrentQueue<long> _idsToConvert;
    private static List<Proxy> _proxies;

    public ProxyWorker(int proxyCount, ConcurrentQueue<long> idsToConvert, List<Proxy> proxies)
    {
        _proxyCount = proxyCount;
        _idsToConvert = idsToConvert;
        _proxies = proxies;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Parallel.For(0, _proxyCount, index =>
        {
            ConvertOnProxy(index);
        });
    }

    static void ConvertOnProxy(int proxyId)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var proxy = _proxies[proxyId];
            webClient.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy.Host, proxy.Port);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                if (_idsToConvert.IsEmpty)
                {
                    Logger.Success("Finished processing");
                    return;
                }
                else if (!_idsToConvert.TryDequeue(out var currentId))
                {
                    Logger.Error("Failed to process userID: " + currentId);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ProcessId(currentId);
                    }
                    catch (WebException e)
                    {
                        try { ProcessId(currentId); } catch { Logger.Error(e.Message); }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static async void ProcessId(long currentId)
    {
        var username = await TwitterUtilities.GetUsernameFromId(currentId);

        Program.UsernamesProcessed.Add(username);
        Program.IdsProcessed.Add(currentId);

        if (username == "no_username_found")
        {
            return;
        }

        Program.UsernameCache.Add(username);
        Program.IdCache.Add(currentId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably Twitter throtteling/blocking you for basically running a crawler instead of using their APIs

Comment: 1) ProcessId() does not return a Task, and therefore cannot be awaited. As a result, you will end up with a huge number of concurrent calls to GetUserFromId().

Comment: 2) You're using the queue incorrectly. It's possible to find the queue not empty, and then have TryDequeue() return false because it's now empty. Just call TryDequeue(), and if false, you're done.

Comment: 3) There's no need to limit the iterations over the queue; just loop until TryDequeue() returns false.

Comment: How do you know that the code run only 100 times? Have you seen "Finished processing" message in your log?